# Is there any way i can get the name of the user of the phone(android) in flutter app?

Tags: flutter

Guys I am trying to get the name of the user who uses the phone. Is there any flutter plugin which can provide me this functionality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello you can use this plugin **device_info**, you can see the documentation about it here :
https://pub.dev/packages/device_info#-example-tab-

```
import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';

void getDeviceinfo() async {
  DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin(); 
  AndroidDeviceInfo androidDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo; // instantiate Android Device Information
  IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo; // instantiate IOS Device Information
  print("for Android : ${androidDeviceInfo.product}");
  print("for IOS : ${iosInfo.name}");
}
```

Comment: Well I've seen the package you have mentioned but I don't think it can provide me the user name of the phone in that plugin

Comment: The device_info plugin can get the name that the user named the device, however it cannot get the name of the user

Comment: Oh, could you please add a code snippet above so that I can narrow down my efforts in searching the plugin .

Comment: you can't retrieve the user name from the device(for example for me i use in every user name @mouadmem16 which is not my name). so you can't retrive it from the device. but you can ask the user about his/her name.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I'm sorry that my comments weren't transferring the correct message. But like you said I only want the name assigned to the phone by the user. And if possible please add a code block above so that I can take a look at that